# Прямоугольники вместо текста при использовании нестандартных шрифтов

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, pillow

Мне нужно вставлять имена пользователей на изображение, порой у них бывают имена с "нестандартными" шрифтами, из-за чего вместо текста появляются прямоугольники. Смена шрифта не помогла.

Вот код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import discord

size_card = (885, 215) 
сolor_card = (30, 30, 30)

font3 = ImageFont.truetype("files/img/calibri.ttf", 38)
card = Image.new("RGB", size_card, color_card)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(card)
user = discord.Member

draw.text((239, 98), f"{str(user.name)} #{str(user.discriminator)}", (255, 255, 255), font=font3)
```

Comment: можете привести значения для `size_card` и `color_card`?

Comment: @MaxU 
size_card = (885, 215)
сolor_card = (30, 30, 30)

Comment: Укажите метку языка, библиотеки, что такое `user`. Желательно привести [mre]

Comment: @dIm0n поправил.

Comment: @ddd_ht, приведите в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример, который поможет воспроизвести проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного ошибок терминологии:
То что вы называете "шрифтами", является символами Unicode'а.

В вашем случае, шрифт (`*.ttf`-файл, в данном случае), не поддерживает указанных вами символов юникода (А если быть точнее - полноширинных символов).

Либо поменяйте шрифт на поддерживающий необходимые символы, либо проверяйте каждый символ на наличие в шрифте, и в случае его отсутствия, берите символ из другого шрифта. Например, через библиотеку [fonttools](https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/):

```py
def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
    for cmap in font["cmap"].tables:
        if cmap.isUnicode():
            if ord(unicode_char) in cmap.cmap:
                return True
    return False

check_font = TTFont(font_path)  # font_path - путь к файлу шрифта на диске
for c in your_string:
    if char_in_font(c, check_font):
        ... # рисуем символ стандартным шрифтом
    else:
        ... # рисуем символ "аварийным" шрифтом
```

В качестве "аварийного" шрифта могу посоветовать [Symbola](https://dn-works.com/ufas/)

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код работает правильно:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

User = namedtuple('User', 'name discriminator')

user = User(name="Jonh", discriminator=123)

size_card = (885, 215)
color_card = (30, 30, 30)

font3 = ImageFont.truetype("files/img/calibri.ttf", 38)
card = Image.new("RGB", size_card, color_card)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(card)
draw.text((239, 98), f"{str(user.name)} #{str(user.discriminator)}", (255, 255, 255), font=font3)

card.show()
```

PS для воспроизведения, я создал объект `user` с типом `namedtuple` с соответствующими полями

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD:** вырезка из `docstring` для метода `ImageFont.truetype(font, size, ...)`:

> ```
> :param font: A filename or file-like object containing a TrueType font.
>              If the file is not found in this filename, the loader may also
>              search in other directories, such as the :file:`fonts/`
>              directory on Windows or :file:`/Library/Fonts/`,
>              :file:`/System/Library/Fonts/` and :file:`~/Library/Fonts/` on
>              macOS.
> ```

Т.е. в качестве значения в параметр `font` вы должны передавать либо путь к файлу шрифта в OS либо `file-object` (указатель на открытый файл шрифта).

Comment: Сам код работает правильно. Но как я пояснял в вопросе, может быть "нестандартный" шрифт. Вот попробуйте: Ｂｒｕｎｏ
PS. Проверил так же прямоугольники.

Comment: @ddd_ht, google ничего не знает о таком шрифте. Откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: "шрифты онлайн" в этом проблема.

Comment: @ddd_ht, я думаю для того чтобы использовать онлайновые фонты в Pillow, вам придется сделать их оффлайновыми ;)